# Status all counts

Tags: sql

I have one table like below (MSSql)

```
Name  Status
----  -------
kmk   Success
kmk   Success
mvk   Fail
per   Success
Per   Fail
mvk   Fail
```

I need the query which gives result like below

```
Name Status  Count
---- ------- -----
kmk  Success 2
kmk  Fail    0
mvk  Success 0
mvk  Fail    2
Per  Success 1
Per  Fail    1
```

i tried with `group by` but i got result like below My Query is

```
(Select Name,[Status],COUNT([Status]) As Count From Checking group by [Status],Name)

Name Status  Count
---- ------- -----
kmk  Success 2
mvk  Fail    2
Per  Success 1
Per  Fail    1
```

I tried many ways can you please give me the query

Comment: You should make yourself familiar with GROUP BY clauses and the COUNT function.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your query. Rewrite your question to have a better understanding of your table structure

Comment: I tried with group by but i got output like below Name Status Res
kmk Success 2
mvk Fail 2
mvk Success 1
Per Fail 1
per Success 1

Comment: Try doing an outer join with a table containing the two statuses ("Success", "Fail"), and use your count/group just like you did.

Comment: Or if nothing else works, try a cartesian product of unique names with a 2-row table with your statuses. Then left outer join this cartesian product with your `checking` table to get the count.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following. It works with sqlite3, and depending on your SQL engine, your mileage may vary:

```
select
  name,
  "Success" as status,
  sum(case when status = "Success" then 1 else 0 end) as count
from checking group by name
union
select
  name,
  "Fail" as status,
  sum (case when status = "Fail" then 1 else 0 end) as count
from checking group by name;
```

Result with SQLite3:

```
kmk|Fail|0
kmk|Success|2
mvk|Fail|2
mvk|Success|0
per|Fail|1
per|Success|1
```